# Securely share directories with process users

Tags: linux, permissions

Suppose I have a directory `/clients/bob` which is owned by `bob:bob`

I might grant developers the `bob` group so that they can edit these files, then I can later remove them from this group when they no longer need access.

However what do I do about process users like `www-data`? I don't want to put `www-data` in the `bob` group because this would give Apache access to **everything** and not just the document root of the website. I similarly don't want to give ownership of the document root to `bob:www-data` or `www-data:bob` because this solution doesn't scale when I need to grant two process users access to the directory (suppose I have a cronjob running on another user)

Comment: `I might grant developers the bob group so that they can edit these files, then I can later remove them from this group when they no longer need access.` Ehm. That would grant them access to **all** files from something:bob.  Why not create a group and chrgrp the folder. So not bob:bob but   bob:our_prog_devs. And add the relevant users to that group.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should consider the `www-data` user as “everyone” and grant access accordingly.

If you think the web resource has been secured properly, you could also step away from the basic octal permission system and use Access Control Lists:

```
setfacl -R -m u:www-data:rX my-directory
```

This allows the `www-data` `u`ser to access data and enter directories, starting from `my-directory`. (`-R` is the same as in `chmod`, it means to apply the change recursively.)

To make newly added files and folders also have that ACL, you have to set the default ACL:

```
setfacl -R -d -m u:www-data:rX my-directory
```

Please note that ACLs must be enabled both in the kernel and the mount point. Please refer to the manual of the file system you’re using for that. It is now the default in most Linux distributions, so it may already be available.

Comment: Will newly created files or directories inherit these ACL settings? I have little experience but maybe the OP should also use `-d` option.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski You’re right of course, they won’t inherit non-default ACLs. I will update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think *Access Control Lists* (from Daniel B's answer) are OK. They are powerful for sure. In case you cannot use them, the following less powerful solution may be enough:

1. Create a group especially for this case, e.g. `cl_bob`.
2. Then `chown` the document root (recursively) to `bob:cl_bob`.
3. Add users (including process users) to `cl_bob` group. The user `www-data` should be in `cl_bob` but not in `bob`; developers may need to be in both.
4. Enable `setgid` for the directories:
   `find /clients/bob/document/root -type d -exec chmod g+s "{}" +`
   This way future directories and files created therein will inherit `cl_bob` group regardless of user (process) who creates them.
5. Another user (as in your cronjob example) may be easily added to the group later.

Advantages over ACL:

- Quite simple and well known.
- Easy to inspect with standard tools like `ls -l`.
- Widely supported out of the box.
- Adding (removing) user to the group is a simple operation that generates almost no disk I/O nor takes time. The case may be different while recursively applying ACL metadata.

Disadvantages:

- Not as flexible. User other than `bob` is xor isn't in `cl_bob`, so the group permissions xor other permissions apply, *tertium non datur*. If you want more permission levels (e.g. full read-write, limited read-only, no access) then you need ACL.
- System-wide. You need root access to create a group and to add users to it; crucial information is stored in `/etc/group`. ACL is way more "private", like a filename; ACL metadata is stored within filesystem (yet you still need `/etc/group` and `/etc/passwd` to connect GIDs and UIDs to the real world).
- May generate garbage. Imagine you have removed `/clients/bob` with all the content inside; the `cl_bob` group is now a useless artifact, unless you remember to delete it also. ACL metadata are removed along with the files, there is no garbage left.

Comment: Two awesome answers, thank you. As mentioned in the bounty comments, I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 so ACL will be an option for me. Since the major advantages of your solution over ACL are just simplicity and widespread support (whereas the advantages of ACL are reduced garbage and increased flexibility) I prefer the ACL option and will be selecting that as my top answer. Although this answer definitely deserves a thumbs up!